# Better GL performance with Radeon HD 7750M card?

Tags: drivers, graphics, amd-graphics, radeon, mesa

I'm running Ubuntu Studio on an EliteBook 8470p with a Radeon HD 7750M GPU. I've got `xserver-xorg-video-radeon` installed, the `radeon` and `amdgpu` drivers are loaded without  errors according to `dmesg`. Yet in a game I get only 10 FPS on this laptop, while on another, which has an Nvidia GeForce 520M installed with the proprietary drivers, I get 15 FPS.

But according to [videocardbenchmark.net](https://www.videocardbenchmark.net/compare/2476vs70/Radeon-HD-7750M-vs-GeForce-GT-520M), the AMD card has a 4 times better performance than the nVidia card - so in theory I should be getting 75 FPS - but in any case more than with the nVidia card, not less.

Do you have any suggestions how to increase my game framerate ?

P.S.: One thing I noticed is that `glxinfo` gives `Mesa` as vendor:

```sh
~$ glxinfo | grep -i vendor
server glx vendor string: SGI
client glx vendor string: Mesa Project and SGI
    Vendor: Mesa (0x1002)
OpenGL vendor string: Mesa
```

Essentially, I want to disable Mesa (which renders on the CPU if I'm not mistaken) and force everything to run on the AMD card.